# Cannot see linked service or management hub in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am new to azure cloud infrastructure, I am trying to create a azure data factory, which I did now I am trying to create a linked service to another SaaS provider "salesforce". I am not seeing any place to create one.

I have consulted the following links, but could not find anything yet.

I cannot see management hub
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/author-management-hub

or in azure portal
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-linked-services

Thank you

Comment: Hi @Arup Sarkar, If my answer is helpful for you, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Arup Sarkar, do you have any other concerns?

Answer (score 0):

Please ref this tutorial: [Copy data from and to Salesforce by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-salesforce)

- This article outlines how to use Copy Activity in Azure Data Factory
  to copy data from and to Salesforce. It builds on the Copy Activity
  overview article that presents a general overview of the copy
  activity.

You could create the Salesforce linked service from here Data Factory UI on Portal:

Manage-->linked services-->new-->Salesforce:
[image]

Configure the Salesforce:

[image]